# Restrict network connection to virtual machine alone-VMWare

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ethernet, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to restrict a Ethernet/Wifi Connection to the virtual machine alone and not to the host operating system? I am using VMWare workstation on windows with centOS and Ubuntu as my guest OS in VMWare. I want to connect the guest OS to a network but not the host. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/277616/block-internet-access-except-for-a-virtual-machine-and-windows-update

This may point you in the right direction.

## Answer By Arctor:

> "For VMWare you can disable IPv4 and IPv6 under the adapter settings this will disable the network on the host but still allow it to be accessed by the VM if it is set to Bridged. You can re-check IPv4 to temporarily enable the internet to allow updates if you are having an issue an update fixes."